# JSON Web Token Security

Tags: security, single-page-application, jwt, json-web-token

I've been working with JSON Web Tokens and reading up on how to make an app more secure. When a user is a authorized, the token is signed, and a token will be placed in the Authorization Header. This token can then be placed in localStorage, sessionStorage, or cookieStorage. The last option came out top to be the most secure option, but I was wondering if any features of a JSON web token, or any middleware, or perhaps JSON Web Encryption (not really sure how this works) that would prevent a malicious attacker from intercepting/grabbing that token, and using it for future requests to the app's APIs, since all that's needed is a request with that token for a dumb server to respond for the information requested.

Comment: This is very broad and not really a good fit for this site. You might get better answers at [security.se].